# how to run binary executables in robotframe work on centos7?

Tags: linux, shell, centos, robotframework

`Run Process  /path to binary executable/cc1  -p/path to the file to be excuted/abc.prf -its -m /path to the other file to be executed/xyz.ctl  shell=true  cwd=path to binary exexutable`

some thing like this

`Run Process /home/abc/xyz/ipslc -p/home/abc/aaa/ipsl/$3/$3.prf -its -m /home/abc/ipsl/XE/bbb/ips/regre/$1/$2.ctl  shell=ture  cwd=/home/abc/xyz/`

am i correct??

is it possible to run binary executables in robotframe work???

will binary executables run in robotframework in linux??

Comment: have you tried doing what's in your question? `Run process` should be able to run any process inside robot that you can run outside of robot.

Comment: yes i tried .the output of that process is it has to generate server.its and client.its which was not generated.two processes(client and server) has to run simultanously

Comment: even though the process is incomplete the test case is getting passed i am not understanding how to know whethere process is running completely or not -@BryanOakley